# Invalid syntax ^ error while running pwssh

Tags: python, linux

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pxssh
import getpass
try:
    s = pxssh.pxssh()
    hostname = raw_input('hostname:')
    username = raw_input ('username:')
    password = getpass.getpass ('password:')
    s.login (hostname,username,pawssword)
    s.sendline('uptime')
    s.prompt()
    print s.before
    s.sendline('ls-l')
    s.prompt()
    print s.before
    s.sendline('df')
    s.prompt()
    print s.before
```

---

```
root@kali:/var/myPY# ./ssh.py
File "./ssh.py", line 19

                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
root@kali:/var/myPY#
```

I do not see anything on line 19, please help me

Comment: You have a `try` without an `except`

Comment: With `try` you need `except` or `finally` or `else`.

Comment: Take some time to go through the [Python Tutorial, section "Exceptions"](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)

Comment: When a parser/compiler gives an error on a line behind the end of your code, the parser expects something that it couldn't find. In your case it was a missing 'except'. In other languages you'll find it happens for missing }'s, )'s, missing string quotes and everything else that needs to be properly closed as well.

Comment: Also note that `ls-l` should be `ls -l` and that running scripts as root is almost never a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

A `try` block must be followed by least one `except` or a `finally`. You aren't catching any exception here, so just get rid of the `try` part:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pxssh
import getpass

s = pxssh.pxssh()
hostname = raw_input('hostname:')
username = raw_input ('username:')
password = getpass.getpass ('password:')
s.login (hostname,username,pawssword)
s.sendline('uptime')
s.prompt()
print s.before
s.sendline('ls-l')
s.prompt()
print s.before
s.sendline('df')
s.prompt()
print s.before
```